# VB.NET Icon will only work in Small Folder icon option only , If I use View Large Icons I see Blue Default

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, icons

Got an annoying issue it's Visual Basic 2010 I changed icon where the assembly name.
I got a good icon it has lots of sizes, or I tried diff sizes like 64x64 128x128 nothing seems to work
I only see the icon when i do View > Details so it's small icons in the folder, but if i have view large icons It doesn't work. I even used the same icon on VS 2008 and it worked.

Can't figure out what is the issue? Maybe framework? I use on this program 2.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with you, I'm using windows 7 Professional 64 bit
Please try following step

1. Convert your image icon from http://iconverticons.com/
2. right click at your project -> Property , and select "application"
   on left tab
3. select you icon file
4. Build your exe file again
5. if it still doesn't work, please try to refresh , windows may still not
   reload your new icon image if not !! , root windows ,

I still has same problem at a first time , but when wait for some time , seem windows reload icon

Answer (score 0):

Type ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache in a command window as otherwise your new icon may not appear if the file name of the .exe stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for brining an old thread but I have the solution...

Struggled for ages to find an answer to this and even in VS2013 it still seems that Imagelist has problems with this. Had numerous icons with 256x256 and yet it still wanted to revert to the original 16x16 and then upsize!?!?

finally I got to this..

```
ImageList2.Images.Add(New Icon(My.Resources.GoodIcons.File_Xls, 256, 256))
```

pretty simply declaring the icon as a new icon with 256x256 parameters - Although if you then select the of the Imagelist to say 48x48...

```
ImageList2.ImageSize = New Size(48, 48)
```

You get a 48x48 image (from the 256x256 bitmap it creates)
Much easier than going through all of your icons and 'Deleteing' the lower res ones!

Hope this helps anyone searching for same situation!

Chicken x

Side note - this will also 'upsize' icons that don't have 256x256 (which look rubbish) - so check your icon file to make sure each icon has 256x256 if not, just use the largest one you want (ie 96x96 / 64x64 / 32x32)